# How to pull remote repo only get its last commit in Git?

Tags: git

In this below scenario:

[image]

In the remote repo there is a `dev` branch, and in my local repo there have a `dev` branch too.

I have a requirement, I want to pull the remote_repo `dev` to my local repo `dev` branch, but only want to last commit, I mean the `commit:20190906`.

How to do with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`git cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick):

```
git checkout dev
git fetch
git cherry-pick origin/dev # last commit only
```

But you then need to decide what to do with your local branch `dev`: do you (force) push it back to `origin`? That would override the history of `dev` on `origin`.